# Cloned sdbx partition to sdax. Now Ubuntu boots from sdax instead of sdbx

Tags: backup, clone

I just wanted to do a backup and now this. How can I boot from sdbx?

```
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt: UUID="0sMY0p-eQ1c-FSgC-YZ2r-KqrD-pgqX-j52nld" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="40a62c0a-3804-4300-a74c-736e0d204a6d" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="SYSTEM_DRV" UUID="DA73-C7A9" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="cf1203b0-69e5-4a0b-b2b2-dde28a86b712"
/dev/sda2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="a26826a3-cff7-40e8-8dd5-6cb3ae233901"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Windows" UUID="01D3C5E5EB110460" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="02acf9d7-c84f-4de6-9d8e-bbbb15ba4c06"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="LENOVO" UUID="409E49D39E49C260" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="bbdad025-10e7-45d1-b7c5-e211401cec7e"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="WINRE_DRV" UUID="BE9242019241BEA1" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="edd3b155-ff31-454b-b71f-42ccdeb40d2b"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="LENOVO_PART" UUID="566C46286C4602EB" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="a5ea2569-0adf-4bf6-b2f8-710b129cadf3"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="LRS_ESP" UUID="127F-617A" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="e273824a-8c25-482f-87b1-358e2eb98189"
/dev/sda8: UUID="06b22cda-2b73-4aad-adc8-1ce49398637e" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="740e5c1d-a1c9-4308-946c-7abf605df87c"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="37A6-DED4" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="96df314c-68f6-4bfc-8ad9-067777c97ef5"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="22fe5bd0-c317-4e1e-b003-8c76f6c0053c" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="76b62ac5-fa6b-4808-aee8-d5313788b494"
/dev/sdb3: UUID="06b22cda-2b73-4aad-adc8-1ce49398637e" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="e014c55f-4852-4565-ba22-f77d353a6a29"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="702b8928-9624-4f27-bbe5-2cebee123172" TYPE="swap"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="e1c5c8f0-7e80-42cf-b095-79b063e57af4" TYPE="swap"
```

I cloned the partition from a internal ssd to another internal hdd with clonezilla.

Comment: Please edit your question to elaborate on exactly which method of cloning or backup you used. Please add the complete output of the command `sudo blkid`

Comment: OK, you have 2 partitions with the same UUID. That is what is causing your problem. See my answer for the fix.

Comment: Both partitions are encrypted. New UUID is grayed out.

Comment: You will have to modify the instructions in my answer to mount the encrypted partitions. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The button for a new uuid is greyed out in gparted. Is it possiblr just to remove the cloned partition and then update grub?

Answer (score 0):

If you cloned partion A into partition B

1. Boot into a live Ubuntu session on the computer
2. Using Gparted set a new UUID on partition B
3. Update grub on partition A

> ```
>  sudo su
>  mount /dev/sd__ /mnt
>  mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
>  mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc 
>  mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
>  mount --bind /usr /mnt/usr 
>  chroot /mnt  
>  update-grub (may get an error about not finding a grub drive on the usb)
>  grub-install /dev/sd_
>  CTRL-D on keyboard.
>  umount /mnt/dev 
>  umount /mnt/proc
>  umount /mnt/sys 
>  umount /mnt/usr
>  umount /mnt
> ```

4. Update grub on partition B

> ```
>  blkid (copy sd__'s UUID)
>  mount /dev/sd__ /mnt
>  leafpad /mnt/etc/fstab, fix UUID
>  mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
>  mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc 
>  mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
>  mount --bind /usr /mnt/usr 
>  chroot /mnt  
>  update-grub (may get an error about not finding a grub drive on the usb)
>  grub-install /dev/sd_
>  CTRL-D on keyboard.
>  umount /mnt/dev 
>  umount /mnt/proc
>  umount /mnt/sys 
>  umount /mnt/usr
>  umount /mnt
> ```

5. reboot, should...

Boot into the Partition B system (may be listed as Debian, PartA should be an option below)
     check partion in use: lsblk, sd__ is /

> ```
>  sudo update-grub
>  sudo grub-install /dev/sd_
>  reboot
> ```

6. Boot into the Partition A system

   check partion in use: lsblk, sd__ is / 
    if this works you are done